# Unable to use PyQGIS since python is unable to import qgis libraries

Tags: qgis-3, ubuntu, pyqgis-3

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed QGIS 3.4.4 Madeira on my laptop. I am learning PyQGIS. I have found these lines of code that I have executed in my terminal but I get a traceback saying that python is unable to use the QGIS libraries.[image] Can you help me with this.

Comment: Where did you find those lines and why do you think they are applicable to your setup? They almost certainly are not.

Comment: I found those lines in a PyQGIS course on Udemy. I had no reason doubt. Can you share me with the correct lines. Thank you.

Comment: To be honest, I just figured out that using python3 instead of just python will work. Now it works. Thanks for your comment anyway.